# Data integrity check on SQL help please

Tags: sql, count, distinct

I have a query:

```
Select distinct yearend, customerid from table1
```

This returns, with a row count of 3 (bottom right of SSMS):

```
Yearend      CustomerID
2011-03-31   3
2013-10-31   5
2013-12-31   6
```

What I need to do is come up with a count of the above, just returning the value of 3.

I've tried several variations on this but cannot just return '3' as a counted total.

Comment: You should *probably* include one or two of the variations you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to `COUNT` the results of your query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT yearend, customerid
    FROM table1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT CustomerID)
FROM table1
GROUP BY CustomerID
```

Comment: True, i would add in `SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT whatever)' but he hasnt mentioned it yet what needed to be distinct

Comment: took a guess at customerid

Answer (score 0):

Do you need distinct count?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT yearend, customerid
FROM table1
)
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it certainly will make a difference if there are duplicate records in `table1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(*) from
(select distinct yearend, customerid from table1);
```